# How to get back a valid object from python in C++ while this object has been construct using handle<>?

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I want to allocate a buffer in C++ and provide it to python as a memoryview object.
To do so, I expose this function using boost::python :

```
object* Allocator()
{
    void* buff = my_alloc_function(char, size);
    Py_buffer pybuffer;
    int res = PyBuffer_FillInfo(&pybuffer, 0, buff, size, false, PyBUF_CONTIG);
    if (res == -1)
        return NULL;
    handle<> obj_handle(borrowed(PyMemoryView_FromBuffer(&pybuffer)));
    object obj = object(obj_handle);
    return &obj;
}
```

I want also to be able to provide a C++ destructor called by python once the count ref of the python object goes to zero.
I managed to have my destructor called by python and get the returned pointer by Allocator() as a parameter of my destructor.

Following, the currently C++ function called by python :

```
void Destructor()(object* pyMemoryView_object) const 
{
    Py_buffer* py_buffer = PyMemoryView_GET_BUFFER(pyMemoryView_object);
    my_free_function(py_buffer->buf);
    PyBuffer_Release(py_buffer);
}
```

Everything seems to go well until the destructor is called...

The problem I have is that the Py_buffer `py_buffer` has a valid address but contains scrapped members (as shown as 0xcccccccc in debugger).

My first question is :

**How to get back a valid Py_buffer object in C++ from python while this object has been constructed using handle<> and wrapped into a python object ?**

My second question will be :

**Do I have to call PyBuffer_Release() since it could be called by python after the call to Destructor() ?**

Thanks for all your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it work.

Here is the code the two functions (without return policy when exposing them):

```
PyObject* Allocator()
{
    void* buff = my_alloc_function(char, size);
    Py_buffer pybuffer;
    int res = PyBuffer_FillInfo(&pybuffer, 0, buff, size, false, PyBUF_CONTIG);
    if (res == -1)
        return NULL;
    return PyMemoryView_FromBuffer(&pybuffer);
}

void Destructor()(object pyMemoryView_object) const 
{
    Py_buffer* py_buffer = PyMemoryView_GET_BUFFER(pyMemoryView_object.ptr());
    my_free_function(py_buffer->buf);
    PyBuffer_Release(py_buffer);
}
```

The important point that I have learned is that when returning an object to python, use `PyObject*`.

When getting an object from python, use `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example, I'm going to be surprised if returning the address of an object allocated on the stack is acceptable. Just return an object by value ?

Comment: I have the same results if I put these members in a static scope.